# Can't display image on image

Tags: java, image, swing

I tried to show background and character, for a project I'm trying to make (a game).

When I display one of the images, I can't see the other one.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;

public class Main{
    private static final Keys jeez = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int x = 250;
        int y = 250;
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\milkg\\Desktop\\Game\\background.png"));
        JPanel background = new JPanel();
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        background.add(picLabel);
        BufferedImage myPicture1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\milkg\\Desktop\\Game\\background.png"));
        JPanel character = new JPanel();
        JLabel picLabel1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture1));
        character.add(picLabel1);
        JFrame Window = new JFrame("Something");
        Window.setSize(1280, 720);
        Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(Window.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Window.setLocation(200, 100);
        Window.setResizable(false);
        Window.add(background);
        Window.add(character);
        Keys Key = new Keys(x, y, Window);
        Window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the layout manager of the container that you're using. Your JFrame (actually its contentPane) uses a BorderLayout, and by adding a second component to this container without accounting for this, you're covering the first one. Solution: use a different layout manager such as a GridLayout.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Note how the forum thinks your variables are class names because you don't follow the Java conventions. Most of your variables are correct, but not all. Be consistent!

Answer (score 0):

> image on image

If you want to display one image on top of a background image, then you need to add the foreground image to the background image.

So the basic logic would be something like:

```
JLabel foreground = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
JLabel background = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
background.add( foreground );
window.add( background );
```

Note there is no need to use the panels just to display a JLabel. The content pane of a JFrame is a JPanel so you can add the label directly to the frame.

> trying to make (Game)

However, if you are trying to make a game you may want to do custom painting so you can control the placement of each image:

The basic logic in this case would be:

```
JPanel gamePane = new JPanel()
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background, ?, ?, this);
        g.drawImage(foreground, ?, ?, this);
    }
};
```

Now the foreground image will paint on top of the background image.

Of course you should design a proper class with methods to allow you to move the "character" on the "background".

Comment: But now i made a new class and added, what u told me and i cant do g.drawImage because background and foreground are JLabels.

Comment: @lior, Your question was not very detailed, so I gave two suggestions. You use the appropriate suggestion based on your complete requirements.

Comment: @lior  "But now i made a new class" on SO it means "I need to post a new question".  Accept / upvote answers which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, bot paths in the code you uploaded point to the same file.
Then, displaying label over label simply by adding the labels on top of each other will not work.

What I suggest is to create a subclass of JPanel() where you override the paint component method, for example :

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(yourImage,x,y,imageObserver);
   }
};
```

Comment: `displaying label over label simply by adding the labels on top of each other will not work.` - yes it will. I just showed you how.

Comment: Well you did it in a more complex way. I was talking about simply doing :
window.add(label1);
window.add(label2);

I tested this way and it doesn’t work, but I have no doubt that your way does work.

Comment: It is not a more complex way. It is understand the parent/child relationship between Swing components. If you add multiple components to the same panel then the components are displayed in 2D space. I was simply showing that if you want to use components, then you need a frame --> background --> foreground hierarchy. If you want to do custom painting then you can control the order in which the images are painted so you paint the background before the foreground.

Comment: The first time I did not understand your method, and I did not know that you could add components to a JLabel. But I now get the idea of your method.